# How to create icons with tauricon?

Tags: tauri

I'm testing out [Tauri](https://tauri.studio/) for a hobby project, but got stuck when trying to generate an icon with **tauricon**. After creating a new project with Svelte that ran, this is what tried:

```
npm install @tauri-apps/tauricon
npm audit fix --force
npx @tauri-apps/tauricon .\app-icon.svg
```

---

EDIT:

Ok, so I've kind of fixed it, but not sure why this is necessary to install the package this way. If someone could explain, that would be useful.

```
npm uninstall @tauri-apps/tauricon
npm install --save-dev @tauri-apps/tauricon
npm audit fix
npx @tauri-apps/tauricon .\app-icon.svg
```

The error I get says: `npm ERR! could not determine executable to run`

Comment: Actually it seems that the command that broke it was `npm audit fix --force`.

Answer (score 1):

using `npm audit fix --force` is not recommended, as this could break your project. You have to start another one and only use `npm audit fix` if you really want. I didn't use it at all and the icon feature worked well. So first try to create your icons, then run `npm audit fix`.